# How to add currency symbols into the currency list?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

How can I add currency **symbols** into the currency **list**?

This is the code,

```
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
<div class="form-micro">

    <select onchange="window.location.href=this.value" name="custom-currency-selector" id="custom-currency-selector">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code)?>"
            <?php if($_code == $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                selected="SELECTED"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_name ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

will output,

```
    <option ...>Euro</option>
    <option ...>British Pound</option>
    <option ...>Danish Krone</option>
    <option ...>Swedish Krona</option>
    <option ...>Swiss Franc</option>
    <option ...>United States Dollars</option>
```

But I need to add their symbols after the text,

```
    <option ...>Euro &euro;</option>
    <option ...>British Pound &pound;</option>
    <option ...>Danish Krone DKK</option>
    <option ...>Swedish Krona SEK</option>
    <option ...>Swiss Franc CHF</option>
    <option ...>United States Dollars $</option>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,Tealou ,it is  `possible` ,you can get this using below code

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($cuurencycode)->getSymbol();
```

Your  modified code is

```
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
<div class="form-micro">

    <select onchange="window.location.href=this.value" name="custom-currency-selector" id="custom-currency-selector">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code)?>"
            <?php if($_code == $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                selected="SELECTED"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_name ?><?php Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_code)->getSymbol(); ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```